# ng-change and onchange not working for <input type="file">

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<button ng-click="controller.foo()">Click<button>
```

is working.

But

```
<input type="file" ng-model="logo" onchange="controller.foo()">
```

is not working. Also

```
<input type="file" ng-model="logo" ng-change="controller.foo()">
```

is not working.

The error I get first first not working:

> product-page4:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: controller is not
>   defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.onchange (product-page4:1)

For the second I get no response at all.

How to make this work for `input`?

Comment: You should create a [mcve] to let us help you.

Comment: How did you define `foo()` method in your controller?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide, nice name. `function foo() { alert("works"); }`

Comment: How do you bind your Angular controller to the html? I'm assuming you are using Angular.

Comment: I am using it. This PapaJohns code. It is bind, according to first element which works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to interact with controller's methods in your view, you better define them using `$scope`:

```
$scope.foo = function () {
  alert("works");
}
```

And then invoke the method from HTML like so:

```
<input type="file" ng-model="logo" ng-change="foo()">
```

But it should be possible with `this` (I didn't test it, but as I remember...)

**Controller:**

```
this.foo = function () {
  alert("works");
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" ng-model="logo" ng-change="controller.foo()">
```

Comment: Thanks, @Commercial Suicide, is there a way to do it without using `$scope`?

Comment: @guautemoczihuataneho, yes, I have updated the answer. I didn't work with Angularjs for a long time, but as I remember, it should work

Comment: In the first error the controller is not part of html's window element and you'r using pure JavaScript. In the second one you are using angular and need to follow angular convention. If you deside to use angular you can use ng-change=foo().  Another option is use $scope.$watch('logo', function(value){}).